# Controller file was loaded but class does not exist

Tags: magento

I am having trouble getting around this error in Magento:

"Controller file was loaded but class does not exist". (Full stack at bottom)

I am essentially trying to follow this tutorial: [Create new module “HelloWorld” – in Magento](http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/).

...though I am using my own company/class names etc. instead of "hello world"

I am having trouble finding good documentation on Magento in general, and I am very new at it...

can anyone provide some common causes, advice, or insight? I am swamped, googled this for hours, check permissions and file structure. You name it.

```
Trace:
#0 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(306): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Controller file...')
#1 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(282): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_inludeControllerClass('/var/www/dev_ml...', 'Foo_Wr...')
#2 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(195): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_validateControllerClassName('foo_Wr...', 'index')
#3 /var/www/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(158): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /var/www/dev/app/Mage.php(459): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /var/www/dev/index.php(65): Mage::run()
#6 {main}
```

Comment: If you include 1. The full path to your created controller file and 2. the contents of your controller file, people will be better able to help you.

Comment: Here we have some update. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110701/controller-file-was-loaded-but-class-does-not-exist/61191569#61191569), It will help you

Answer (score 40):

That error means that magento found a file for your controller where it expected to `(app/code/local/Namespace/Module/controllers/FooController.php)` but that the class inside didn't have the name it expected (it wasn't **Namespace_Module_FooController**).

Answer (score 22):

Hope you got this sorted, just to let you know I looked at the same tutorial, and I think this error may be fixed by the addition of the <?php declaration to the start of the php code samples.

Comment: This was exactly my problem; I copied and pasted directly from the tutorial and couldn't figure out where I was going wrong...thanks!

Comment: Me too , Because i am making same mistake

Answer (score 15):

You might find [this article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world), (part of a [larger series](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento)) (self-link) more helpful, and it goes more into the why of what you're doing, which will enable you to better debug things yourself in the future.

As for your specific error

> Controller file was loaded but class does not exist

This means magento was able to correctly require/include the file you placed your controller in **but** the controller class was misnamed.  Controllers should be named

```
Packagename_Module_ControllernameController
```

and located in the folder

```
app/code/local/Packagename/Modulename/controllers/ControllernameController.php
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error because I was using following code in my CartController(Overridden)

```
require_once "Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php"; 
class Muk_Mycart_CartController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
}
```

instead of  following code of line

```
require_once "Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php"; 
class Muk_Mycart_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
}
```

I was missing "Checkout"  in "Muk_Mycart_CartController".This is error because I was using following code in my CartController(Overridden)

My directory structure was like this

```
\app\code\local\Muk\Mycart\controllers\Checkout
\app\code\local\Muk\Mycart\controllers\Checkout\CartController.php
```