# Controller file was loaded but class does not exist?

Tags: mysql, apache2, magento-1.7

I am having trouble getting around this error in Magento:

"Controller file was loaded but class does not exist". (Full stack at bottom).

I am essentially trying to follow this tutorial: http://phpshiner.blogspot.in/2012/09/simple-custom-payment-module-part-1.html in magento.

I am having trouble finding good documentation on Magento in general, and I am very new at it...

can anyone provide some common causes, advice, or insight? I am swamped, googled this for hours, check permissions and file structure. You name it.

```
Trace:
    #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(326): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Controller file...')
    #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(293): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_includeControllerClass('C:\Apache24\htd...', 'Mage_Checkout_O...')
    #2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(196): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_validateControllerClassName('Mage_Checkout', 'onepage')
    #3 C:\Apache24\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #4 C:\Apache24\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #5 C:\Apache24\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #6 C:\Apache24\htdocs\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #7 {main}
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/15155893/1616003

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller class name is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I also got that error when I was using WinSCP.
Problem is that my file was not saved correctly.

When I have saved it again and then reload my page and error was gone.

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If not able to locate the issue.

Please go there(Standard.php)
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard

In this function please add like this and execute the page.

```
protected function _includeControllerClass($controllerFileName, $controllerClassName)
{
        echo $controllerFileName."#############".$controllerClassName;
        echo "<br/>";
```

You will get the issue module and location

Thanks
Annadurai